# Grub not found after install ubuntu16.10

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I have upgraded to 16.10 today by install fresh along with windows. My problem when i choose ubuntu entry it not load grub menu. In order boot to menu i have to use commands from grub > root (hd1,10) chainloader +1 boot . This problem never show before.
Anyone can tell me what exactly my problem is? How to fix it
My system
Laptop asus running ubuntu 16.10 amd64 
uefi disabled
Use easybcd to add entry to ubuntu
I have partitions home and boot (sdb11) seperate on hdd

Comment: UEFI & EasyBCD do not mix well. UEFI is boot manager (menu) and then you do not need EasyBCD as boot manager. Grub is both boot manager & boot loader for Linux. And then you may have installed Ubuntu in BIOS mode? May be best to see details:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: No i don't use UEFI! I install standard ubuntu on MBR. I have install several times before without problem. But today this happen!

Comment: Then EasyBCD uses the ancient grub4dos to chainload to grub2 installed in PBR or partition boot sector. But grub2 does not recommend that it be installed to a PBR as it has to convert to blocklists and become less reliable. Boot-Repair may be able to reinstall grub. But you would have to manually update grub4dos or EasyBCD settings.